# How to test for blank text field when using robotframework-selenium?

Tags: selenium, robotframework, csv

How can I specify blank/empty value for a text field when using the robotframework-seleniumlibrary with a TSV file? For example, I have the following:

```
Textfield Value Should Be       identifier=name1       Chris
Textfield Value Should Be       identifier=name2
```

I want to test that name2 is blank. I have tried leaving it blank (which returns a message about an incorrect number of arguments. I have tried "", which looks for a pair of quotes, and '' which enters a single quote, and selenium seems to look for that

Answer (score 32):

You can use either a single backslash `\` or special variable `${EMPTY}` to create an empty string in the test data. User guide has the details: [Robot Framework User Guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html).

Comment: ${EMPTY} should work very well and it will be easier understood when reading the test case again... I would try to avoid backslash...

Comment: Yes, ${EMPTY} is more meaningful than \ (backslash)

Comment: Is ${EMPTY} a built-in variable?

Comment: Other way is to include the `value` attribute of element in the xpath and assert the xpath `//input[@class='xyz' and @value='']`

Answer (score 11):

Yes, `${EMPTY}` is a built in variable.

There are many examples, see an example [here](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html)

Answer (score 0):

`${EMPTY}` is good for a blank value but, surprisingly, it didn't work for an empty value.

I found what I was looking for. The field I was verifying had no value in its value attribute and I wanted to verify it. It was returning `''` as the value and when using `${EMPTY}` it couldn't find `''''` instead. Such a minor thing but ended up solving what I needed, so it depends what you're seeking to verify.