# How to search for empty string/compare two strings in Robot Framework

Tags: string, if-statement, compare, robotframework, is-empty

I have read this question

[How to test for blank text field when using robotframework-selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900360/how-to-test-for-blank-text-field-when-using-robotframework-selenium)

as well as the [two](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html) [links](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html) to the Robot Framework documentation in the answers but I still don't get how to check if a variable is empty.

I want to do this

```
if var A equals var B then
   do something
else
   do something else
```

where A is a string that can both contain something as well as be empty and where B is empty or null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can be achieve using  many different ways some are as follows, use whichever fits for you

1. this way you can check two variables equals OR not

   ```
   Run Keyword If    '${A}'=='${B}'   do something    ELSE    do something
   ```
2. this way you can check if both of your variable are None or not in one go

   ```
   Run Keyword If    '${A}'=='None' And '${B}'=='None'    do something
   ```
3. using following also you can get if your variables are equal of not if both values are equal it will return true

   ```
   Should Be Equal    ${A}    ${B}
   ```
4. if both values are NOT equal it will return true.

   ```
   Should Not Be Equal   ${A}    ${B}
   ```

for more information go through [this docs](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Should%20Be%20Equal)

there is also `${EMPTY}`  variable in robot framework which you can use to check if variable is empty or not

Comment: So "Run keyword If '${A}'=='${EMPTY}' ? Why do you write this with apostrophes?

Comment: How do you combine example 3 and 4 with an if-clause?

Comment: @hensti   for first query..... reason behind wrapping it in apostrophes because if your variable differs like A is int and B is string then it will treat both as string then it will perform operation, without apostrophes only similar datatype variables can be compared

Comment: @hensti for second query ....`Run Keyword If    '${A}'!='${Empty}'    And    '${B}'!='${Empty}'    Should Be Equal   
 ${A}    ${B}` likewise you can do for 4th as well

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure I follow your answer on my second query. `should be equal ${A} ${B}` then what? If the condition is satisfied or not?

Comment: it run only if both A and B are NOT empty, any one of them is empty then it wont check for equality, it wont run `should be equal ${A} ${B}` this keyword

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I meant how do you use Should (not) be Equal on its own? That is, (in pseudocode) `Should be equal ${A} ${B} then A+B else A*B`. No `Run Keyword If` involved. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @hensti the `Should Be Equal` keyword is an assert, it will pass if the 2 are equal, or fail if not, and that's it. Such branching "if a do X else Y" is not done with it, but with `Run Keyword If`, like in the first example of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like this is working:

```
${aaax}=     set variable  aaa aa ba baavaa
${aaaxx}=    set variable  aaa aba baavaa
${aba}=      set variable  aba

${res1}=     run keyword and return status  should contain  ${aaax}     ${aba}
${res2}=     run keyword and return status  should contain  ${aaaxx}    ${aba}

log to console  ${EMPTY}
log to console  res1: ${res1}
log to console  res2: ${res2}
```